# Need help to understand async calls in angular js

Tags: angularjs

I have a main controller and nested controllers within it. In the main controller I have defined object by async query to the service, and try to use the object in the nested controller. But in the object in the nested controller is empty, cause it fires before it will be updated in the main controller.

As I understand, asyncronous query should updates the scope after data obtain?

```
.controller('MainController', ['$scope', function($scope) {

    $scope.uData = {};
    $scope.uDataCurrent = {};

    $scope.usersData = usersFactory.getUsersData().query(
        function(response) {
            $scope.uData = response;
            $scope.uDataCurrent = $filter('filter')($scope.uData, {'user':$scope.myuser});
            $scope.uDataCurrent = $scope.uDataCurrent[0];
        },
        function(response) {
            $scope.message = "Error: "+response.status + " " + response.statusText;
    });
})]

.controller('NestedController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    console.log($scope.uDataCurrent); // returns empty object
}])
```

Service:

```
    .service('usersFactory', ['$resource', 'baseURL', function($resource,baseURL) {

        this.getUsersData = function(){
            return $resource(baseURL+"/index.php?app=users&format=raw&resource=user",null,  {'update':{method:'PUT' }});
        };

    }])
```

Comment: Can you post your factory code too?

Comment: The nested controller does not "fire". Its initialization code runs when some element in the dom is instantiated that has a controller assigned. The query callback will set `uDataCurrent` much later. If you use binding the ui will be updated with the new data when it is received.

Comment: @hsiung check the initial code

Comment: @Tamas Hegedus if I use a function which starts on ng-init and uses the object? Will it use the empty object?

Comment: @MikeDiam  Yes, it will be the empty object.

Comment: @Tamas Hegedus so how to run the function when the object will be not empty?

Comment: The only guaranteed place you will have access to the data once it comes back is in that callback function. In this situation, you can't really fire a function in the child controller since you are handling the callback inside the parent controller. Like Tamas said, you can use binding so that the value in the child will get updated when the parent gets the data, but are you trying to accomplish something else?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`$scope.$watch`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watch).

```js
angular.module("App", [])
.controller("OuterCtrl", ["$scope", "$timeout", function($scope, $timeout) {
  $scope.users = null;
  
  $timeout(function() {
    $scope.users = ["John", "Jack"];
  }, 500);
}]).controller("InnerCtrl", ["$scope", function($scope) {
  
  $scope.changeCount = 0;
  
  // TODO: Bad practice to rely on outer scopes here as its not enforced
  // to have an OuterCtrl scope as parent scope. In this example every
  // occurrences of InnerCtrl is embedded in an OuterCtrl in the html
  $scope.$watch("users", function(newValue, oldValue) {
    // This code runs when the users array is changed
    $scope.changeCount++;
  });
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.7/angular.js"></script>

<div ng-app="App">
  <div ng-controller="OuterCtrl">
    <div ng-controller="InnerCtrl">
      <div>Change count: {{changeCount}}</div>
      <div>Users</div>
      <div ng-hide="users"> Loading...</div>
      <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="name in users">{{name}}</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```